# how to join from 2 fields to 1 field on another table

Tags: sql-server

on sqlServer i have 2 tables:

```
table1: Students => studentName=david, class1Id=2,class2Id=4

table2: classes=> classId=2, className="class1"

        classId=4, className="class2"
```

`class1Id` and `class2Id` relate to  `classes.classId`

i want to do sql query to get :

```
studentName=david, className1="class1",className2="class2",
```

I know to do join between 2 table but not like that

thanks!

Comment: The root of this problem is the design of the table is flawed. This has what is known as repeating groups. It violates 1NF and should be avoided at all costs. Consider how poor this design becomes when you need to allow a third class per student. You have to change the table and change ever single query that looks this information. The relationship between students and classes should be a many to many. To properly handle this you need a bridge table for StudentID and ClassID. Your professor has handed you a losing hand here. They want you to query a poor design. Shame on them!!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `JOIN` to `Classes` twice:

```
Select  S.StudentName, 
        C1.ClassName As ClassName1, 
        C2.ClassName As ClassName2
From    Students    S
Join    Classes     C1  On  C1.ClassId = S.Class1Id
Join    Classes     C2  On  C2.ClassId = S.Class2Id
```